# dealing with a function $f$ that is a radial distribution.

Tags: fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

How do you show that if the function $f$ is a radial distribution then

$x\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}-y\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=0$?

Comment: what do you mean by "radial distribution" ?

Comment: The question posted is **not** the question in the title!

Comment: @user247327 sorry, realised that the title was misleading,and changed it! thanks for pointing it out! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider polar coordinates $x=r\cos(\theta)$, $y=r\sin(\theta)$. Now $f$ is radial if and only if $f_\theta=0$; the chain rule says $$f_\theta = f_x\frac{\partial x}{\partial\theta}+f_y\frac{\partial y}{\partial\theta}=-y f_x+xf_y.$$

So the correct version of the assertion is that $f$ is radial if and only if $yf_x-xf_y=0$.

Comment: Oops, sorry! I think I made a mistake while writing the question!

Comment: Hi David, your reasoning works perfectly if $f$ is a function. But here $f$ is a distribution and so, to be precise, we need to apply the differentiation operation to text functions and then reverse the operation back to $f$ by the definition of distributional derivatives.

Comment: @SamWong can you elaborate a bit more on using differentiation operation because i am struggling on it. Thanks

Comment: @SamWong Yes, if $f$ is a distribution and not a function then the partial  derivatives of $f$ are defined in terms of test functions, as you say. So what?  That doesn't invalidate anything I wrote here...

Comment: The problem is, if $f$ is a distribution, then one can not conclude that $f_\theta=0$ by the definition immediately. We have to actually "calculate" that  $f_\theta=0$ as William's comment under this problem(c.f. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3566727/show-that-if-f-is-a-radial-distribution).

Comment: @SamWong But the fact that $f\circ R_\theta=f$ if and only if $f_\theta=0$ is utterly trivial. (Because it follows immediately from the definitions, no cleverness required).

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich this may just be a matter of definitions, but I don't see how $f\circ F_{\theta}=f$ if and only if $f_{\theta}=0$ is trivial. The definition I'm using is $f_{\theta}(\phi)=-f(\phi_{\theta})$. Is this the definition you are using?

Comment: @heron1000 I have no idea what you're talking about, I never said anything about any $F_\theta$. In fact $f$ is radial if and only if the _pariial derivative_ $f_\theta$ vanishes. What's your definition of "radial"???

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich sorry typo, it should be $R_{\theta}$ instead of $F_{\theta}$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich My definition of "radial" is $f\circ R_{\theta} = f$ for all $\theta$.

Comment: @heron1000 Ok. the following are equivalent: (i) $f\circ R_\theta=f$ (ii) $f\sirc R_\theta=f\circ R_0$ (iii) $f\circ R_\theta $ is independent of $\theta$ (iv) $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}f\circ R_\theta=0$ (v) $f_\theta=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Computing the partial derivatives to polar coordinates we get $(x^{2}-y^{2})/r f_r=0$. So what is true is $f(r,\theta)$ depends only on $\theta$. A radial function is one which depends only on $r$ so the statement is wrong.

On the other hand $f$ is radial iff the partial derivative w.r.t. $\theta $ is $0$ and this transaltes to $xf_y-yf_x=0$.

Comment: I changed the question, realised a mistake that was made while typing it out.